# Strange result when implementing multiple return statements c++

Tags: c++, mbed, rvo

I have a very strange problem with my application. I am using STM Development board NUCLEO-F411RE with the MBED Online IDE. My function myObj() returns an object; a value of the returned object is printed to the LCD.

I seem to identify some problem, possibly with Return Value Optimization in the compiler/linker.
I cannot explain the issue in incorrect application code.

When adding a second return statement in myObj() strange behavior starts to occur.
With a single return statement all works fine, therefore I am suspecting some fundamental problem.

Expected LCD result: dar
Incorrect LCD result: Bar

Code snippets:

```
class charStream {
    public:
    charStream();                                       // Constructor
    ~charStream();
    void in(char c);
    void undoIn();
    char out();
    bool empty();
    int size();
    void readReset();
    char read();
    bool readEnd();

    private:
    charStreamElement *firstElement;
    charStreamElement *lastElement;
    charStreamElement *readElement;
    int streamSize;          
    };

charStream myObj() {
    charStream ch;
    charStream ch2;

    ch.in('d');ch.in('a');ch.in('r');
    ch2.in('D');ch2.in('A');ch2.in('R');

    return ch;       
//        return ch2;
//When above line is uncommented lcd prints Bar. When commented lcd prints dar
}

int main() {
        lcdPrintStr(&lcds, myObj());
        do{} while(1);
}



void charStream::in(char c) {
    charStreamElement *newElement;

    newElement = new charStreamElement(c,NULL,firstElement);
    firstElement->setPrevious(newElement);
    firstElement=newElement;
    if (streamSize==0)
        lastElement=firstElement;
    streamSize++;
}

class charStreamElement {
    public:
    charStreamElement(char c, charStreamElement *prev, charStreamElement *next);                                // Constructor
    ~charStreamElement();
    char elementValue();
    charStreamElement *getPrevious();
    charStreamElement *getNext();
    void setLast();
    void setPrevious(charStreamElement *prev);

private:
    char value;
    charStreamElement *nextElement;
    charStreamElement *prevElement;
};

charStreamElement::charStreamElement(char c, charStreamElement *prev, charStreamElement *next) {
    value=c;
    nextElement=next;
    prevElement=prev;
}

void charStreamElement::setPrevious(charStreamElement *prev) {
    prevElement=prev;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: You haven't shown sufficient code to be precise - but I don't see a copy constructor declared...

Comment: `charStream` probably has a rule-of-three violation

Comment: If I understand your question/example correctly, that leads me to one question: Why do you have (are trying to have) two return statements in your function? A function should have at most 1 (definite) return statement. Are you trying to return two objects?

Comment: At the very least you need to show the definition of `charStream::in()`, and as @M.M mentioned, your class will likely need some other functions defined (such as a copy ctor).

Comment: @callyalater There is no rule about the number of returns in a function.  this is doubly true when you have different branches that return different things.  It is pointless in this case but it should not do anything.

Comment: I didn't know how to phrase my statement about return statements properly (as I am well aware of branches). I was trying to say that in his example the second return would never be reached because the function would return from the first one.

Comment: @callyalater Which is okay.  you can have as many statements after a return as you want.  Its dead code but it does not affect the program.

Comment: @NathanOliver Would the MBED Lightweight C++ handle that properly though? That is why I was thinking that his "dead code" might be screwing things up if his compiler didn't handle that properly.

Comment: Thanks for comments already. I've added some more of the relevant code. Indeed I don't intend to return multiple objects in my application but I have encountered this strange behavior (it could well be application error , but I don't know yet). I also thought that the second return statement should be dead code and therefore could never influence the outcome...

Comment: You need to make a copy constructor for `charStream`.

Comment: @NathanOliver, thanks. Solved by using a copy constructor. I will put the solution in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by introducing a copy-constructor.

The function myObj() then uses the copy-constructor and returns the correct result even with the second return active (not that this will be used in a real situation, but it highlights how to go about in such cases).

```
charStream &charStream::operator=(const charStream &copy) {
    char c;
    charStreamElement *temp;

    streamSize=0;
    firstElement=NULL;
    lastElement=NULL;
    readElement=NULL;

    temp=copy.lastElement;
    while (temp!=NULL) {
        c=temp->elementValue();
        in(c);
        temp=temp->getPrevious();
    }
}


charStream myObj() {
    charStream ch;
    ch.in('d');ch.in('a');ch.in('r');

    charStream ch2 = ch;
    ch2.in('D');ch2.in('A');ch2.in('R');
    return ch;       
    return ch2;
}
```

Objects ch and ch2 are created on the stack and are independent of each other.
LCD now correctly prints **dar** as one would expect.